# jquery attribute injection with index

Tags: jquery, attributes

I need to add attribute "data-lightbox" with paremeter + index to each `<a>` element inside each `.gallery-popup`. The code works, but what I need is that for example: in first `.gallery-popup` i have `<a>` elements with `data-lightbox="gal-1"` in second `.gallery-popup` attribute value is `"gal-2"` (for each a element) and so on.

```
var thumbnailInterval = setInterval(function() {
  if ($('.offer .box_info_potos div .gallery-popup li a').length) {
    console.log('found' + $('.offer ').length);
    clearInterval(thumbnailInterval);

    $('.offer .gallery-popup a').each(function (index) {
      var a = $(this).get()[0];
      a.setAttribute('data-lightbox', 'gall' + index);
      console.log(a);
    });
  }
}, 100);
```

Comment: Hello - I'm not 100% clear on what the problem is you're having. Is it that the index isn't starting on 1? Or something else?

Comment: What's the issue? You say the code works fine.

Comment: Hi @James @Rory,

I have:
`gallery-1
   a atr=1
   a atr=1
 gallery-2
   a atr=1
   a atr=1`
what I need is:
`gallery-1
   a atr=1
   a atr=1
 gallery-2
   a atr=2
   a atr=2`

PS. Sorry if I'm unclear... I'm new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

you could use parent index, like:

```
...
$('.offer .gallery-popup a').each(function (index) {
    var a = $(this),
        parentIndex = $(this).parents('.gallery-popup').index() + 1; //index start with 0
    a.attr('data-lightbox', 'gal-' + parentIndex);
    console.log(a);
});
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In this version all a elements in every .gallery-popup have index "gal-1".

Comment: Badtakoti https://jsfiddle.net/JakubPL/agwpndht/1/ - it's part of the code... one of gallery. I have 6 galleries on each page. My attribute has to be injected into all <a> tags.